# OpenSSL in Python 2.5.2 not working

Tags: python, linux, ssl, openssl

I am attempting to build Python 2.5.2 with SSL as a separate binary using

> ./configure
>   make
>   make altinstall (with and without the -lssl option)

I did check first that I have openSSL both the regular and development package:

> $ dpkg --get-selections | grep ssl
>   libio-socket-ssl-perl
>   libnet-ssleay-perl
>   libssl-dev
>   libssl-doc
>   libssl1.0.0
>   libssl1.0.0:i386
>   openssl
>   python-openssl
>   ssl-cert

I downloaded Python 2.5.2 and edited the following lines in Modules/Setup.dist:

> _socket socketmodule.c
>   SSL=/usr/local/ssl
>   _ssl _ssl.c \
>          -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
>          -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto

There are numerous blog posts on this issue and here are two that I've seen (I can't post more than 2) - describing the process I have tried:
http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-python-25-with-ssl-support.html
http://paltman.com/2007/11/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251

But after doing the configure, make etc as above, when I do python2.5 to test it, this happens:

> >>> import ssl
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "`<stdin`>", line 1, in `<module`>
>   ImportError: No module named ssl

I'm basically out of things to try - would appreciate any help or pointers as to what to check or things to do to make it work. I understand that Python 2.7 has SSL already, but for other compatibility reasons I have to use 2.5. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SSL support in `httplib.HTTPSConnection` (and others) and the `ssl` module are two different things.

You probably have enabled SSL for the SSL-enabled libraries. However, there is no `ssl` module for Python 2.5. Instead, you may want to use the `OpenSSL` module, which provides similar features.

If you want the code that depends on the `ssl` or `OpenSSL` module, you may need to split the code a little. For example:

```
try:
    import ssl
    USE_OPENSSL = False
except ImportError:
    import OpenSSL
    USE_OPENSSL = True
```

Then, you may have to distinguish what you code does depending on which module was loaded.
(If you only need Python 2.5, use `import OpenSSL` directly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however I tried import OpenSSL in python2.5 and it also said module not found.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu 11.10, [python-openssl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/python-openssl/filelist) doesn't contain the files for Python 2.5. You'll have to install it yourself too.